# PHP DateTime Alternative

Tags: php, datetime

So I think that this will be a bit of an odd question, but is there any sort of alternative to PHP DateTime?

I'm currently developing an application for an organization and the server is running PHP 5.1. I have absolutely no control over the server, so unfortunately, I'm unable to update the site to a newer version of PHP. However, I stupidly forgot to check in what version DateTime came into existence, and it turns out it was introduced in PHP 5.2.

I could spend an hour or so rewriting the code to not use DateTime, but I'd have difficulty doing so without functions to add time intervals.

Is there any strong alternative to DateTime, such as something that is existed before it was introduced in PHP 5.2? Alternatively, is it possible to get the DateTime class from another source and include it in my script?

Comment: 5.2 was released over 7 years ago.  Why not make the case to them that they are long overdue for an upgrade.

Comment: http://pear.php.net/package/Date predates the native DateTime, but covers just as much functionality.

Comment: @gview I've been making that effort for as long as I've been in this position. Unfortunately, it's a website for a University student organization, and I'm forced to use web space provided to us by the University. And they won't upgrade because bureaucracy.

Comment: @mario I think this is perfect. I didn't want to have to spend two hours writing a script to add and subtract dates, and it looks like this package provides the exact functionality I need! Perfect!